Dynamically filter points layer data with one or more filter values through style variable in OpenLayers?
I have created layer using WebGLPointsLayer with flatstyle. I want to build functionality to where user can apply filter to filter data on map.
Below are the scenarios: When user has not selected any region, it should show all region data. When user select single region, it should show single region. When user select multiple regions, it should selected region related data on map. This is not working with dynamic value. It will work when I hardcoded multiple region in a style.
I am using latest OpenLayers version.
Openlayer Doc for Expression: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_expr_expression.html
{
  variables: {
    // regionSelected: '',
    multiRegionSelected: [],
    countrySelected: '',
  },
  filter: [
    'all',
    // Single Region selection
    // [
    //   'any',
    //   ['==', ['var', 'regionSelected'], ''],
    //   ['==', ['get', 'region'], ['var', 'regionSelected']],
    // ],

    // Multiple Region selection with hardcoded filter - working fine
    ['in', ['get', 'region'], ['literal', ['MA', 'CA', 'FL']]],
    [
      'any',
      ['==', ['var', 'countrySelected'], ''],
      ['==', ['get', 'country'], ['var', 'countrySelected']],
    ],
  ],
  'circle-radius': [
    'interpolate',
    ['exponential', 2],
    ['zoom'],
    5,
    4,
    15,
    1536,
  ],
  'circle-fill-color': ['match', ['get', 'hover'], 1, '#ff3f3f', '#006688'],
  'circle-displacement': [0, 0],
  'circle-opacity': 0.95,
}


Set dynamic filter value:
{
  variables: {
    // regionSelected: '',
    multiRegionSelected: [],
    countrySelected: '',
  },
  filter: [
    'all',
    // Single Region selection
    // [
    //   'any',
    //   ['==', ['var', 'regionSelected'], ''],
    //   ['==', ['get', 'region'], ['var', 'regionSelected']],
    // ],

    // Multiple Region selection
    // Dynamic filter not working when user select one or more region
    // When user doesn't have any region selected  it should show all region data
    [
      'any',
      ['in', ['get', 'region'], ['literal', ['var', 'multiRegionSelected']]],
      ['==', ['var', 'multiRegionSelected'], 0], // To load all region when no region selected
    ],
    [
      'any',
      ['==', ['var', 'countrySelected'], ''],
      ['==', ['get', 'country'], ['var', 'countrySelected']],
    ],
  ],
  'circle-radius': [
    'interpolate',
    ['exponential', 2],
    ['zoom'],
    5,
    4,
    15,
    1536,
  ],
  'circle-fill-color': ['match', ['get', 'hover'], 1, '#ff3f3f', '#006688'],
  'circle-displacement': [0, 0],
  'circle-opacity': 0.95,
}

To Update style variable dynamically, I have used updateStyleVariables
pointsLayer.updateStyleVariables({
    countrySelected: 'us',
    // regionSelected: 'MA',
    multiRegionSelected: ['MA', 'CA', 'FL'],
  });

Here is the complete example: https://codesandbox.io/s/accessible-forked-vf7w6l
Expected result When user select one or more region, map data should filter accordingly.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78843488/10118270 and https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/16093#issuecomment-2307078478  As variables cannot be arrays the alternative would be to update the style object and call setStyle instead of using variables.

Thanks Mike!! WebGLPointsLayer doesn't have setStyle method and event update through set method also not working.
Like this:
layer.set('style', newStyle); layer.get('source').refresh();

It looks like you need to rebuild the layer as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-points-layer.html, or you could try using WebGL Vector layer as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-vector-layer.html
